# How to use multiple Executor Service in one method.?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Here is my example but it does not execute. It's only working correctly for my first thread pool but the second thread pool was not run. Is it the correct way or not?
If it's correct, where did I make the mistake and if it's not, how do I implement multiple executor services?

In my example the save API executed successfully, and the book appointment method calls the book API successfully, but after the book API, the code does not execute and I'm wondering why.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyTestClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Create class object
        MyTestClass  myObj = new MyTestClass();
        // Create List A
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("Test1");
        a.add("Test2");
        a.add("Test3");
        a.add("Test4");
        //Create List B
        List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add("Test1");
        b.add("Test2");
        b.add("Test3");
        b.add("Test4");
        b.add("Test5");
        b.add("Test6");
        b.add("Test7");
        b.add("Test3");
        b.add("Test4");
        b.add("Test5");
        b.add("Test6");
        b.add("Test7");
        //Call my method
        myObj.myMethod(a, b);

    }
    //Multi-threading example in appointment book method execute first api but its not called the second api
    void myMethod(List<String> listA, List<String> listB){
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listA.size());
            List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String strA : listA) {
                tasks.add(Executors.callable(new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        processA(strA);     
            }
                }));
            }
            try {
                //Execute first thread pool for save
                threadPool.invokeAll(tasks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error while running threads");
            }
            threadPool.shutdown();
            //Call book appointment api
            bookAppointMent(listB);

    }

    //Book appointment
    void bookAppointMent(List<String> listB) {
         ExecutorService threadPool2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listB.size());
            List<Callable<Object>> tasks2 = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String strB : listB) {
                tasks2.add(Executors.callable(new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // Add task
                        processB(strB);     
            }
                }));
            }
            try {
                //Execute thread pool2
                threadPool2.invokeAll(tasks2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error while running threads");
            }
             //Shutdown pool-2
            threadPool2.shutdown();

    }

    //Save appointment
    public void processA(String a){
        //Here its save API
        System.out.println("Save A successfully...." + a);
    }

    //Book Appointment In this method only first api called but second one is not called
    public void processB(String b){
        //Here is First API call - This only called
        System.out.println("Appointment booked successfully...." + b);
        //Here is second API call - Its not called
        processAfterAppBooked(b);
    }

    //Process after book app
    public void processAfterAppBooked(String b) {
        //Second api call - its not execute
        System.out.println("After appointment booked " + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile, unless A and B implement List. If you wanto help with code that doesn't work, post the actual code that doesn't work, so that wen copy and paste that code, compile it and execute it by ourselves. Not pseudo-code.

Comment: Should run. But without a [mcve] (yours is missing the Complete bit) I can't confirm this.

Comment: ok i will post the complete code.

Comment: why do you need 2 executors here?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I have two API one for save and another one for book appointment save executed successfully but book appointment executed partially

Comment: @BlueCloud what `proccessAfterAppBooked` is supposed to do? When running the code from your question I can see that it's executed entirely. How do you know that it was executed partially? Perhaps you are doing something else in your original code which is missing from the sample code?

Comment: @lgor Nikolaev I done my original code same like that sample code I will remove my first thread pool it will work properly how is it happens I'm just wondering for that behavior

Comment: @BlueCloud As I said - I ran the code and it was running fine - all stages completed. Unless your code does something else it should be working just fine.